# What is the difference between authState and user in AngularFire Authentication?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am working on integrating Authentication into my Angular+Firebase app using Angular Fire. While doing so, I have come across numerous examples that use `authState` to get a hold of the user's metadata such as their `displayName` and `uid`.

**Note:** `fireAuth` is of type `AngularFireAuth`.

Here is a sample:

```js
this.fireAuth.authState.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          return {uid: user.uid, email:user.email, displayName:user.displayName}
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    );
```

But I noticed, in the [Documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md#5-getting-started-with-firebase-authentication) for AngularFire, they simply used `user` instead of `authState`. So I refactored the code a bit and ended up getting similar results:

```js
this.fireAuth.user
    .subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {
        console.log(result.displayName);
      } else {
        console.log("USER IS NOT LOGGED IN");
      }
    });
```

Here, `result.displayName` is producing the same result when I use `fireAuth.user` as well as when I use `fireAuth.authState`. So what is the difference between the two?